# C++ structs defined in header and implemented in cpp

Tags: c++, struct, implementation

How can i make sure that the somecolor that i implement keeps his value when you use it in another class?

**struct.h**

```
struct Color{
   unsigned char r;
   unsigned char g;
   unsigned char b;
};
Color someColor;
//if i define the color here it says...:
Color someColor = {255,255,255}; //error: data member inializer not allowed
```

**struct.cpp**

```
struct::Color someColor = {255,255,255};
```

**someotherclass.cpp**

```
struct *str = new struct();
str->someColor.r //is not the correct value /not set
```

Comment: Please show real code. You can't have a `struct` called `struct`.

Comment: Judging from the last line, I think we're missing the vital information that `someColor` is a member of a class, not a global variable. To answer the question, we'll need to know (a) if that is indeed the case; and (b) whether it there should be just one instance of it associated with the class itself (a static member) or with each object separately (a non-static member).

Answer (score 6):

You need to *declare* it in the header:

```
extern Color someColor;
```

and *define* it in the .cpp file:

```
Color someColor = {255, 255, 255};
```

Side note, your syntax `struct::Color` is highly misleading. It's parsed as `struct ::Color`, and in C++ terms, it's equivalent to `::Color` or just `Color` (unless you're inside a namespace).

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to rename your `struct` to `mystruct` for the sake of making it valid C++. It seems like you want to provide a default constructor for `mystruct` that initializes its `someColor` member to `{255,255,255}`. Pre-C++11, you would have to do that like this:

```
mystruct::mystruct()
{
  someColor.r = 255;
  someColor.g = 255;
  someColor.b = 255;
}
```

Alternatively, if you give `Color` a constructor that takes 3 values, you could do this:

```
mystruct::mystruct()
  : someColor(255, 255, 255)
{ }
```

However, in C++11 you can do aggregate initialization in the member initialization list, so you don't need to give `mystruct` a constructor:

```
mystruct::mystruct()
  : someColor{255, 255, 255}
{ }
```

In fact, in C++11 you're allowed to initialize non-static non-const members inside the class definition as you have attempted to do:

```
Color someColor = {255, 255, 255};
```

Answer (score 4):

You should write it like this:
**struct.h**

```
struct Color{
   unsigned char r;
   unsigned char g;
   unsigned char b;
};
extern Color someColor;
```

**struct.cpp**

```
#include "struct.h"    
Color someColor = {255,255,255};
```

**someotherclass.cpp**

```
#include "struct.h"
Color newColor;
newColor.r = someColor.r;
```